# undefined control sequence error while compiling script using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I get the following error when compiling the minimal tex script appended at the end of this post:

```
(/texmf/tex/generic/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 
! Undefined control sequence. 
l.24 \pgfdeclareplothandler
                            {\pgfplothandlercurveto}{}{%
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance,

gf7

minimal tex sample:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\title{title}
\author[M]{M}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->](0.5,0.5) -- (0,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I comment the line `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` I am able to compile your MWE. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: MWE is running well with PGF3.0.

Comment: Indeed, crixstox and ferahfeza are right: the library `arrows.meta` is a new feature of TikZ 3.0.0 hence if you don't have install it, comment the call to compile the example. Otherwise, if you need it, you have to make sure having the new version of TikZ installed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by a package update to pgf/TikZ.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by a package update to pgf/TikZ.