# Identifying a fix for an Undefined control sequence (\pgfdeclareplothandler) error

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, updating

I would like to identify a fix for the following error:

> "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
>   2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers. code.tex" ! Undefined control sequence. l.24 \pgfdeclareplothandler
>                              {\pgfplothandlercurveto}{}{%

After some searching, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164254/undefined-control-sequence-error-while-compiling-script-using-tikz) appears to be the most relevant thread.  I recognize that my issue is also a candidate for being off-topic.

Please see the MWE .tex file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[]{presentation}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cancel}
\title[]{Title}
\subtitle[]{Subtitle}
\author[short name]{Full name}
\date[short date]{\today}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section[Outline]{}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[]
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
Frame content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The .cls file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{presentation}[]
\LoadClass[]{beamer}
\RequirePackage{beamerthemeMontpellier}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}    
\RequirePackage{graphicx,url}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,amsmath,verbatim,lscape,color}
\RequirePackage[english,short,num]{isodate}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
% load additional `tikz' libraries
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% beamer settings
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\subtitle{\docsubtitle}
\institute{}
\date{}
% get title and author
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tntitle}{\@title}
\newcommand{\tnfrom}{\@author}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{%
}%  % end AtBeginDocument
\AtEndDocument{%
}% end AtEndDocument
```

The file:

```
...\MiKTeX2.9\tex\generic\pgf\librariespgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
```

appears to be the issue.  What I have tried to date is the following:

1. Update MiKTeX
2. Remove pgf and pgfplots folders from C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex and re-install packages.

Any thoughts or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as information in case someone wants to try: not reproducible with TeXLive 2016

Comment: Probably you have a partially updated installation. I don't have MikTeX but add `\listfiles` and look for stale versions/odd paths. You don't need `\makeatletter` in a `.cls` and ought not have `\makeatother`. You don't need to load `graphicx` so often, especially since other things are already loading it. `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used. Don't load: `graphicx`, `color`, `lscape`, `url`. Pass `english` as a class option, but specify the variant you want instead. The `arrows` library is deprecated. `shapes` has been superceded.

Comment: @cfr, Thanks for the general advice and for the idea to check out the file paths.  It turns out that I had a pgf folder at the path: C:\localtexmf\tex\generic, and also here: C:\localtexmf\tex\plain (I understand this to be my local texmf tree?).  I deleted the folders.  Problem solved.

Comment: @crf would you like to write an answer? Or close as "solved in comments"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments